# Grails plugin configs being overridden by app

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a Grails 2.4.4 plugin that I am using in a 2.4.4 app. In that plugin's `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['/images/**', '/css/**', '/js/**', '/plugins/**']
grails.resources.resourceLocatorEnabled = true
grails.project.target.level = 1.8
grails.project.target.level = 1.8
```

However when I include this plugin in my app and do a `grails run-app`, it is obvious that these configs are being overridden by the app.

**Is this the default behavior of Grails?** Meaning *should* the app be overridding the plugin's configs? If not, what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using the assets plugin too ?

Comment: Thanks @ThePearl (+1) however no, I am not (and for reasons outside the scope of this question) **cannot** use the assets plugin.

Comment: I was guessing, if you are using assets, that might be causing the overrides. sorry. Now, I read your question again. Got it. Yes, that's the expected behavior, I believe. If you want, you can set the required config's for the plugin, inside in your app.  Example,  I set the following in my app's config.groovy -- `grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 8181`, so port 8181, is passed to the underlying spring plugin's config. Make's sense ?